# Creating a timer using Lua

Tags: timer, lua

I would like to create a timer using Lua, in a way that I could specify a callback function to be triggered after X seconds have passed.

What would be the best way to achieve this? ( I need to download some data from a webserver that will be parsed once or twice an hour )

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `lalarm`, here:
http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/

Example (based on src/test.lua):

```
-- alarm([secs,[func]])
alarm(1, function() print(2) end); print(1)
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to use alarm in a simple way to call a function every minute?

Comment: Did you look at the code?  There is a file "test.lua" in the lalarm archive.

Comment: It's not possible to set to two alarms in a row, otherwise the second would overhide the first one.

Answer (score 8):

If milisecond accuracy is not needed, you could just go for a coroutine solution, which you resume periodically, like at the end of your main loop, Like this:

```
require 'socket' -- for having a sleep function ( could also use os.execute(sleep 10))
timer = function (time)
    local init = os.time()
    local diff=os.difftime(os.time(),init)
    while diff<time do
        coroutine.yield(diff)
        diff=os.difftime(os.time(),init)
    end
    print( 'Timer timed out at '..time..' seconds!')
end
co=coroutine.create(timer)
coroutine.resume(co,30) -- timer starts here!
while coroutine.status(co)~="dead" do
    print("time passed",select(2,coroutine.resume(co)))
    print('',coroutine.status(co))
    socket.sleep(5)
end
```

This uses the sleep function in LuaSocket, you could use any other of the alternatives suggested on the [Lua-users Wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction)

Answer (score 1):

If it's acceptable for you, you can try [LuaNode](https://github.com/ignacio/luanode). The following code sets a timer:

```
setInterval(function()
    console.log("I run once a minute")
end, 60000)
process:loop()
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading this thread and others I decided to go with [Luv](https://github.com/luvit/luv) lib. Here is my solution:

```
uv = require('luv') --luarocks install luv

function set_timeout(timeout, callback)
  local timer = uv.new_timer()
  local function ontimeout()
    uv.timer_stop(timer)
    uv.close(timer)
    callback()
  end
  uv.timer_start(timer, timeout, 0, ontimeout)
  return timer
end


set_timeout(1000, function() print('ok') end) -- time in ms

uv.run() --it will hold at this point until every timer have finished
```

Answer (score 0):

use Script.SetTimer(interval, callbackFunction)

Answer (score 0):

On my Debian I've install [lua-lgi](https://packages.debian.org/fr/sid/lua-lgi) packet to get access to the [GObject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GObject) based libraries.

The following code show you an usage demonstrating that you can use few asynchronuous callbacks:

```lua
local lgi = require 'lgi'
local GLib = lgi.GLib

-- Get the main loop object that handles all the events
local main_loop = GLib.MainLoop()

cnt = 0
function tictac()
     cnt = cnt + 1
     print("tic")
     -- This callback will be called until the condition is true
     return cnt < 10
end

-- Call tictac function every 2 senconds
GLib.timeout_add_seconds(GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 2, tictac)

-- You can also use an anonymous function like that
GLib.timeout_add_seconds(GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 1,
                         function()
                            print( "There have been ", cnt, "tic")
                            -- This callback will never stop
                            return true
                         end)

-- Once everything is setup, you can start the main loop
main_loop:run()

-- Next instructions will be still interpreted
print("Main loop is running")
```

You can find [more documentation about LGI here](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html)