# What to use in order to count down in seconds from a fixed minute in Lua?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to make a countdown from a fixed minute like 1:00 to 0:00 in Lua.

How can I do that?

Comment: Read this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118799/creating-a-timer-using-lua

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using Corona SDK.

Corona provides a simple way

```
local time = 60
local function decreaseTime()
   time = time-1
   print(time)
end

timer.performWithDelay(1000,decreaseTime,60)
```

have a read here 
http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/timerperformwithdelay