# timer function in Lua for a mobile app - "Closed"

Tags: lua, mobile-application, timedelay

I am working on with Lua scripting language for a mobile app and have a requirement as follows -

The application's aim is to schedule appointments for an individual with a Doctor.
So once a user's appointment is scheduled, for e.g. 8th May @ 4:30 PM, the user should receive a "reminder alert" before an hour i.e. @ 3:30 PM.

I can get the user's date-time value and use the logic that a ***function*** should invoke just before 60 mins of that date-time. And that function contains my "Alert message".
But how to do this?

Can anyone guide me with a clue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118799/creating-a-timer-using-lua

Comment: @Meoiswa I just flagged also

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need:

1. Coroutines
2. os.excecute(sleep) or a sleep function like the one included in LuaSockets

You can find an example of using both here:

[Creating a timer using Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118799/creating-a-timer-using-lua) - 2nd answer